# production server not importing stuff from venv?

Tags: python, django

In my production server I am trying to import another settings file in my venv apps directory and it is not importing causing a 502...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/django/langalang/langalang/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/django/langalang/langalang/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    from spirit.settings import *
ImportError: No module named spirit.settings
```

but the module is clearly there and when I start my production servers venv python interpreter and try to import it, it goes just fine

EIDT ADDING GUNICORN START SCRIPT?:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=project \
    --pythonpath=project \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    project.wsgi:application
```

Comment: is `spirit` a python module containing an `__init__.py` file? Is it on your python path?

Comment: it does contain __init__.py and it is in ../site-packages

Comment: If you load a django shell on the server, can you import `spirit` from there?

Comment: Is it possible that the venv is not being activated when the code is being run otherwise (I'm assuming through wsgi or similar)?

Comment: @ChidG I am not sure about how to check that...I am using nginx/gunicorn, how would I check?

Comment: In your gunicorn start up script (or somewhere before that) you'll need to activate the virtualenv. Check out this blog post for some tips http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/.

Comment: @ChidG I have posted a file that I think is my startup script, but I cannot tell for sure. It has a python path but IDK how to tell if it executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101981/discussion-between-chidg-and-deltaskelta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unable to find the django settings for your project.

- Ensure that you're starting the app with the python binary found in
  your venv and not the system python.
- Ensure that your project is included in `PYTHON_PATH` See: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PythonPath
- You may want to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. See:
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings

Edit:

The most likely issue, that is that you aren't passing the right path to your project in the gunicorn command. Depending on your project's directory structure it's unable to find the settings file for that project. I'm unable to verify this until you've shared the gunicorn command you're using, which produces the error you shared in your question.

Comment: but it is finding MY django settings file. I am importing a settings file in my virtualenvironments apps and extending it, those are the settings that cannot be found...

Comment: important to note that it works in my dev and everything was working with my python path before this

Comment: How is it finding your settings file? `ImportError: No module named spirit.settings`?

Comment: Are you saying that you had django working on this server before?

Comment: I just want to note, that this is an issue I've encountered, and seen others encounter many times, and it's always due to one of the issues I stated above. Could you please paste the gunicorn command you use which causes this error?

Comment: I did have it working on this server before. But I also had my venv incorrectly setup before so it is possible that previous packages were just installed there and I never noticed...That being said I am using digital ocean and I used their django deploy image and I think I have found the start script, but I am not sure, posting to main post...

Comment: I'll take a look at this in the morning. In the meantime could you post your project structure. It's possible that your settings file isn't directly under the project directory where gunicorn is expecting it. I can share the startup script that I use.

Comment: I just want to re-iterate....gunicorn is finding my settings file...this import statement is importing ANOTHER settings file for an app in my venv. The fact that it is failing on the import is proof that gunicorn is finding my project settings file